# Check if object doesn't contain a value not working (JS)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I'm having an hard time solving this problem.

For some reason .hasOwnProperty() is not working.
What I want to do is to create a new object (inside another array) when a value (inside an array) doesn't exist in the array I'm currently looping.
I don't know why, but the first *condition* gets looped **everytime**, instead of being looped only when the condition is satisfied.
P.S I'm looping into JSON. [Example of JSON I'm parsing](http://pastebin.com/9RgHjjZ9)

```
  var keys = [

        "total_kills",
        "total_deaths",
        "total_planted_bombs",
        "total_defused_bombs",
        "total_kills_knife",
        "total_kills_headshot",
        "total_wins_pistolround",
        "total_wins_map_de_dust2",
        "last_match_wins",
        "total_shots_fired",
        "total_shots_hit",
        "total_rounds_played",
        "total_kills_taser",
        "last_match_kills",
        "last_match_deaths",
        "total_kills_hegrenade",

      ];

    var resArray = stats.playerstats.stats;
    var statsArray = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < resArray.length; j++) {
            if (!resArray[j]["name"].hasOwnProperty(keys[i])) {
                resArray[j]["name"] = keys[i];
                resArray[j]["value"] = "None";
                statsArray.push({
                    "name": resArray[j]["name"],
                    "value": resArray[j]["value"]
                });
            }
            if (resArray[j]["name"] === (keys[i])) {
                statsArray.push({
                    "name": resArray[j]["name"],
                    "value": resArray[j]["value"]
                });
            }
        }

    }
```

Feel free to ask for clarifying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if (!resArray[j]["name"].hasOwnProperty(keys[i])) {`

Obviously this statement is wrong. your resArray[j]["name"] is string, not object. In usual you want to check if one object has some enumable property to use hasOwnProperty method.

Comment: Oh, silly me... I didn't see that.
How can I check if a value is not present in the object, so?

Comment: obj.hasOwnProperty.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the original array (stats.playerstats.stats) after the function completes, you will see that it has renamed each key in the array.

That is causing the issue.

```
if (!resArray[j]["name"].hasOwnProperty(keys[i])) {
            resArray[j]["name"] = keys[i];
            resArray[j]["value"] = "None";
```

You are saying here, if this element does not have they keys[i] property, set it to keys[i], and the value to none.  So you end up with (almost) the entire list being set to keys[0]...keys[last element].  So each time, it is setting all the elements to keys[i].

Eliminate those two lines, so that the original json is not altered and it will work better.

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = {name: "total_kills", value: 25555};
```

The property of obj is `name` and `value`, not `total_kills`.

Instead you should code:

```
if (!resArray[j]["name"] === keys[i]) {
```